# In django rest api An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: python, django

I was trying to do a "POST" request but getting this `WinError 10013 Socket` issue in my Django API. I can do the "GET" request successfully, but why am I getting this error on POST request?

```
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions  "POST /api/v5/users/email/ HTTP/1.1" 500 177849
```

Comment: i also tried to run my application on different port like 8080, 8081, 8085, 8000(default) but all ports having same Access permissions issue.

Comment: You should post the code associated with the POST and with GET requests. The error might be there as well. Please provide some more context. Also, make sure to look into the server implementation if it is within your reach. Could be an endpoint problem

Answer (score 0):

Another process might be running on the port. Try `netstat -ban` to list the occupied ports. Also try running server in terminal with **administrator** privilege.

Comment: tried to kill the task which was earlier using that port, also changed the port but nothing worked. also tried to run the server using cmd run as admin but same issue again.